# Using GCM when user logged in from multiple devices at the same time and multiple accounts have been logged in at the same device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, chat

I am using GCM for online chatting application. But I think there are still some area needs to dig deeper. I know GCM gives one registration id per device/app. What if the one user logged out and another logged-in from the same device. How can I be sure that message is sent to relevant user.
To solve this problem I am registering a user everytime he/she either logged-in or register. and when he/she logged-out I am deleting the registration id from my database. I still have some doubt for this approach any information would be very helpful.

Comment: You can `unregister` the `id` also. There is method which will unregister the id from `GCM` as well.

Comment: If I only unregister when a user(say user1) logged out from device (say device1)and do not delete it from the users table listed against (user1). In future, it may create a problem if another user (say user2) logged-in from previous device ( device1) and I want to send message to (user1) who is logged-in from another device (device2). My users table will hold the registration id of the previous device (device1) and user (user1) is logged-in from another device (device2)

Comment: Each and every device have its own `device token` so what you can do is on logout you can delete registration id from your database and unregister  from gcm also.

Comment: Even if you dont delete registration id from your database and only unregister from GCM then also user wouldn't get notification message. But that is what i don't suggest you just unregister and delete it from your db

Answer (score 2):

From the [GCM documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#unregistration-and-unsubscription):

> A client app should call these unregistration and unsubscription
>   functions only if it needs to stop receiving messages. **Developers
>   should never unregister the client app as a mechanism for logout or
>   for switching between users**, for the following reasons:
>
> - A registration token isn't associated with a particular logged in
>     user. If the client app unregisters and then re-registers, the app can
>     receive the same registration token or a different registration token.
> - Unregistration and re-registration may each take up to five minutes to
>     propagate. During this time messages may be rejected due to the
>     unregistered state, and messages may go to the wrong user.
>
> To make
>   sure that messages go to the intended user:
>
> - The app server can maintain a mapping between the current user and the
>     registration token.
> - The client app can then check to ensure that
>     messages it receives match the logged in user.

This means:

- (Re-)Register for GCM on app start, don't unregister on logout
- Store device token in your database on login (map token to account)

  - Storing multiple device tokens for same account should be possible
- Remove device token from database on logout
- To send a notification to a certain account, send it to all device tokens stored for that account
- Additionally, you can check if the notification is addressed to the logged in user on the device itself (send account ID in notification payload)